# В popup(fancybox), есть слайды сделанные в slick slider. Слайды при вызове popup слипаются, как это исправить?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js, fancybox

Суть я описал в название, есть popup, а в нём слайдер. При вызове он слипается, но при скроллинге он восстанавливается. Вызов слайдера прикрепил, после идет вызов fancybox.

```
$(".gooodPopup__slider").not('.slick-initialized').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll:1,
  dots: false,
  swipe:true,
  infinite:true,
  asNavFor: '.gooodPopup__dots',
});
$('.gooodPopup__dots').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3, 
  arrows: false,
  variableWidth: true,
  asNavFor: '.gooodPopup__slider',
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```

fancybox:

```
$('.fancybox__goods').fancybox({
  beforeShow: function() {
    $('.gooodPopup__slider').slick('setPosition');
    $('.gooodPopup__dots').slick('setPosition');
  },
});
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!